# SCons: Forcing SCons to duplicate files

Tags: scons

I have a header-only library consisting of a folder hierarchy and a bunch of `.hpp` files I'd like to install. My problem is, that scons does *not* copy the folder into the build folder.

Here is what my directory layout looks like:

```
root
  SConstruct
  subdir
    SConscript
    the_lib
       subdir_a
         header_a.hpp
       subdir_b
         header_b.hpp
  build
    (...)
```

Here is what I do in `subdir/SConscript`:

```
all_headers = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.hpp'):
        fn  = os.path.join(root, filename)
        all_headers.append((fn, root))

for f, d in all_headers:
    install.AddHeader( f, d )
```

I do this to get the filenames along with their relative paths and then, I use the installer I found in the scons wiki the other day.

Observation: `all_headers` remains empty because the `the_lib` folder does not get copied. I tired `subdir_env.Dir('the_lib')`, but did not change a thing.

After running the script, I have `the_lib/SConscript` in my `build` folder, but nothing else. Of course I can understand that my filesystem walk does nothing in that case.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

The only way out I found was to run a `find -name "*.hpp"` and paste the result into my `SConscript`. Works like a charm now, but since the library is an external one (and maybe some files are added or removed), I thought of a more generic solution without the need to know all headers by name.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I thought of was to use the SCons [Install() builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2938.html), but that is to install actual SCons targets in different locations, and since these header files are not targets, that wont work.

So, in this case, you can use what is called the SCons [Copy Factory](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2989.html).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I tired `Command('the_lib', 'the_lib', Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))` but this creates a dependency cycle. I tried to simply rename, that works with files, but not with directories. Plain `Copy('the_lib', 'the_lib.in')` (since I renamed it, just to be sure) does nothing, while if source and target were files, it works.

Comment: @wal-o-mat, how about this: Copy('dira/theHeader.h', 'dirb/theHeader.h')

Comment: Ah ,sorry, I did not mention that specifying all header files is *not* what I wanted to end up with (therefore the fs walk), but if it takes me too long to make that work, I think I prefer to hard-code the file names.

Comment: I think the problem is that SCons does not 'see' those files. When I look here http://www.scons.org/wiki/AccumulateBuilder it seems like I should be able to interfer with the files in the way I try to. They also use copy and so on. But when the script is being exexuted, it's alone in the build dir.

Comment: @wal-o-mat, Yes, if the files arent actual targets, its hard to get SCons to "see" them, like you say. But this should work: Command('dira/theFile', 'dirb/thefile', Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE")) since the file is now a target.

Comment: Again, this is the same as specifying all the headers by hand and adding them as install targets. I wanted to automate this. What I found out that removing `variant_dir` helps. Thank you for your patient help, but I will give up. That's not worth the effort. I vote up, but don't check "accept" since my original problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

if build is a `VariantDir` then you don't need to copy the file yourself, scons will do it if the header is used in any Builder.

If you want to a list of the files you can use `env.Glob('*/*.hpp')` (but wildcards won't traverse directories, so you need to know the depth)